# trying to sort data from a dictionary in a dictionary iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

can someone explain to me why [tweets count]; is equal to 1 please? the finalDict atm only has one dictionary, but arrayForLetter has 6 and in each of them some values. how do i get all 6 dictionaries from arrayForLetter ?

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [finalDict keyEnumerator];


    id key;
    while ((key = [enumerator nextObject])) {
        NSDictionary *arrayForLetter = [finalDict objectForKey:key];
            NSLog(@"arrayForLetter %@",arrayForLetter);
        NSEnumerator *myEnumerator = [arrayForLetter keyEnumerator];
        id myKey;
            while ((myKey = [myEnumerator nextObject])) {

        statuses=[[arrayResults alloc] initWithAppDictionary:arrayForLetter andAppID:myKey];
        tweets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] ;
        [tweets addObject:statuses];
                [countryList reloadData];   
        //NSLog(@"%@ : %@", key, [finalDict objectForKey:key]);
            }   
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is obvious..  within the while loop you are re-allocating the tweets array and then adding an object. To get count of 6 you need to alloc - init the tweets array before the while loop !

Comment: Thank you, that sounds about right lol. I'm still not sure on what the 'while' loop does. When I'm on my comp I'll give it a go, thanks again